# Suggestions for a lightweight input text box

Tags: asp.net

I am building a simple CMS and need a good solution for an input text box (the one Stackoverflow uses looks great...). The input text boxes from vendors like Telerik etc are just too heavy and feature laden, I'd like a clean simple solution (hopefully that I could just drop into an ASP.NET site).

Comment: What functionality do you want out of the textbox? Have you looked into using jQuery?

Comment: I know what you mean, Microsoft decided that it might be a good idea to not use sprites for the ajax control toolkit editor, so you get about 80 http requests.... woohoo!

Comment: jQuery integration is fine (although I'm not sure I need it...). But i'd like to be able to interact with it from the codebehind page

Comment: if you do any kind of client side interaction (JavaScript) I strongly suggest using jQuery.  
What specific functionality are you looking for? Validation? Input-Masking? ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) works for me. I've used it successfully on MVC / jQuery-rich sites. It's quite easy to configure to remove any functionality / buttons that you don't want the User to see.